# vscode / sublime text make post request on save

Tags: rest, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, visual-studio-addins

For the purpose of rapid development I would like to REST POST (or websocket) changes to my server every time I save a css file. Is there an existing extension that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is none. I used RunOnSave as mentioned previously and Gist as inspiration to make my own extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [RunOnSave](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) and call [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) to make the HTTP POST request.

```
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
"commands": [
    {
        "match": "\\.css$",
        "cmd": "curl -XPOST localhost:8080/hello"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it's possible to read the contents of all css files with that extension?

Comment: You want to post the changed files to the server? Ok that is something different. I thought more of triggering a reload of a local running service.

Comment: Yep, I figured out how to read file contents and so on by reading the docs. Ended up using node http.post instead of curl. Curl is pretty unreliable as many people don't have it on their computers.